# Is $g(f(x,y),y)$ continuous for continuous $f,g$?

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Suppose we have two topologically continuous (preimage of open set is open) maps $f:X \times Y \to Z$ and $g: Z \times X \to W$.

Is the "composition", $h(x,y) = g(f(x,y),x)$ continuous? Why?

My naive attempt is that since $g,f$ are continuous, their composition should be?

Comment: You don't compose $g$ with $f$, but with a map closely related to $f$. Identify that map, and give a reason why that is continuous. Then the continuity of compositions of continuous maps applies.

Comment: the general rule that $g\circ f$ should be continuous doesn't apply since $f$ doesn't map into $g$'s range so your naive attempt won't work(though I'm not sure if the guess is right).

Comment: In your question you have g(f(x,y),y) and in the title f(g(x,y),x) which do you mean?

Comment: @ruler501, I don't think it matters. They are just dummy variables here, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $h=g\circ\left[f,p_{1}\right]$ where $p_{1}:X\times Y\rightarrow X$
is the projection and $\left[f,p_{1}\right]:X\times Y\rightarrow Z\times X$
is the unique map with $q_{1}\circ\left[f,p_{1}\right]=f$ and $q_{2}\circ\left[f,p_{1}\right]=p_{1}$
for projections $q_{1}:Z\times X\rightarrow Z$ and $q_{2}:Z\times X\rightarrow X$.
The continuity of $f$ and $p_{1}$ is a necessary and sufficient
condition for the continuity of $\left[f,p_{1}\right]$. Finally $h$
is continuous as composition of two continuous functions.

Comment: Your acceptance (thank you) inspired me to have a second look at my answer. I discovered that my pen had slipped. I repaired by replacing $p_2$ several times by $p_1$.